# Inject CSS with chrome developer tool?

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

Where can I add CSS to the page I'm viewing? I don't want to add style to one element directly, I want to add a 'document' to a page to debug changes before editing the site's style.css.

Note, there are lots of questions here about 'injecting CSS from a chrome extension', but specifically I want to do it via the 'Chrome Developer Tools' thingy.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> There are multiple ways to do that, and they are also very easy.

---

**First way, inspector-stylesheet:**

Open Inspect Element (<kbd>F12</kbd> Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

Go to **Elements** tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> and type **show elements**), if you are not already there, see the **Styles** tab, now see on right corner, there would be a **+** icon, click it (or long press that icon if it doesn't automatically add ***inspector-stylesheet***), it will add selector of currently highlighted element, just next to the selector, there will a link/button ***inspector-stylesheet***, click it, it will take you a window, where you can add styles.

---

**Second way, Edit as HTML**

Open Inspect Element (<kbd>F12</kbd> Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

Go to element panel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>p</kbd> and type **show element panel**).

Scroll to the **head** element right click on the element and choose **Edit as HTML**, go to the bottom of that element (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>End</kbd>), add your `<style></style>` element there add your style in that element, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

**Third way, Snippet:**

Open Inspect Element (<kbd>F12</kbd> Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

<strike>Go to the **Source** tab, go to the **Snippets** tab, click on the **+ New snippet**, name it whatever you want, and add this:</strike>

Create new snippet <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> type **Create new snippet** hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> , rename the snippet if you want to, and add this (edit the style) :

```
(function(){
    let style = `<style>
/*change your style here*/
body{
        display:none;
    }
</style>`;

document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", style);
})();
```

Save it, run it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

You can also run the snippets by doing this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>p</kbd> type **!** it will show your saved snippets, choose the one you want to run.

To edit or see your snippets, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> type **show snippets**.

---

**In FireFox it's even easier:**

Open Inspect Element (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

Go to **Style Editor**, click the **+** icon and you will be able to edit the style; You can also, import styles, just by clicking the icon next to the **+**.

Comment: I tried creating a snippet - it works when I type cmd+enter, but when I refresh the page the effect is gone. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @Drewdavid I think this the expected behavior, but if you want to run the CSS or JS automatically every time you visit the page, you can use some extension, for example: [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne)

Comment: Hm thanks Stylus. I haven't run across this anywhere. I guess I thought that the point of these snippets was to persist across sessions without needing to create a full-blown extension!

Comment: I like the second option, feel free to edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

I'm not sure if it works, but you'd have to try.

Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>/ (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Mac) to open up the Developer Console and go to the Console tab.

Copy paste the following code (edit the path):

```
$(document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_my_css">');
```

Alternatively, you could edit one property so the inspector-stylesheet.css is created by Chrome, and copy past your CSS source there.

Answer (score 17):

To begin with, this is one reason why I use Firefox for teaching and my own development work. The answer is built in.

As a variation to the above answers, using modern JavaScript, you can add a hard-coded style as follows:

```
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<style> … </style>');
```

or you can add an external style sheet as follows:

```
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<link rel="stylesheet" href="…">');
```

The `beforeend` argument is to help the injected CSS to override previously loaded styles.

If you’re going to do this repeatedly, you can then add it as a bookmarklet, using something like [Bookmarklet Crunchinator](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/bookmarklet.html).

The technique is similar to one I teach in a JavaScript class, where I use `afterbegin` to inject some default CSS, but allow user style sheets to override the defaults.

Comment: this is perfect.. and so easy!

Comment: Thanks for providing a vanilla JavaScript way to do this.

Comment: In your example "stylesheet" is misspelled as `rel="styleshet"`.

Comment: @Paesano2000 Well spotted. Thanks. It works even better if you spell it right :)

Answer (score 5):

Since 2018 in Chrome (65) the browser's integrated DevTools has a feature called **Local Overrides** [1](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-65/#overrides). As such, there is no need for an add-on or extension like StyleBot, Stylish or Greasemonkey.

**Local Overrides** allow rewrites of CSS, JS and DOM on any live site. Changes are saved in a local folder and they override the contents of the live environment.

This can be accessed under `Developer Tools > Sources >> Overrides`

This allows you to select a custom local folder that will contain CSS and JS that will override the current website's own CSS and JS.

[image: Developer Tools > Sources > Over]

Answer (score 3):

Why not a kind of simple framework agnostic one-liner like this?

```
document.body.appendChild(function() {var el = document.createElement('link'); el.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); el.setAttribute('href', 'http://domain/print.css'); return el;}())
```

Seems to work like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

This should work (paste into console, edit arguments in the last line as needed):

```
(function(i,n,j,e,c,t,css){
  css=i.createElement(n);t=i.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];css.href=j;css.rel=e;
  t.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',css);})
(document,'link','//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto','stylesheet','head');
```

This will insert a `<link>`

with an href `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto`

before the closing `</head>`

If there's no head tag in the document you're trying to add a css file to, try `body` as the last argument:

```
(document,'link','//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto','stylesheet','body');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject CSS using snippets in Chrome Devtools. Save and execute the snippet and then invoke it in the console or in another snippet:

```
function insertCss(code) {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';

  if (style.styleSheet) {  // IE
    style.styleSheet.cssText = code;
  } else { // Other browsers
    style.innerHTML = code;
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( style );
}

// run the snippet as follows:
insertCss('span { color: red !important; }');
```

Comment: Hi Michael, can snippets be configured to run automatically when visiting a specific web page, or do they need to be manually run each time? There is a web page that I regularly visit and would like to automatically be altered just for me each time I visit it.

Comment: There are currently chrome extensions that can run scripts on any page automatically. Check out Custom JavaScript for Websites 2, TamperMonkey. Or there are cool extensions like Stylish that let you pick and choose themes, styles from a community of creators. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en

Comment: Thanks I will look into these.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?: "How to Edit Source Files Directly in Chrome" http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/

---

From that article:

Step 1: Launch Developer Tools. Go to View -> Developer -> Developer Tools. Navigate to "Sources"

Step 2: Click the Filesystem tab, then click + Add folder to workspace. You’ll be prompted to locate your work folder and Chrome will ask you to confirm that you Allow access.

Step 3: Edit and Save Your Code and refresh the browser to see your changes

Comment: That only seems to allow me to edit js files... can I use that to edit CSS too?

Comment: CSS works alright for me, not sure if your comment is obsolete or Chrome changed

Comment: You shouldn't give links as the entire answer because what if that page no longer exists. Please type out an entire response and on the bottom you can say that it comes from sitepoint

Comment: The article is great but as ZacharyWeixelbaum explained I had to downvote. If OP edits their answer I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the sources tab in dev tools and right click in the left column, then add folder to workspace and use file explorer to select the folder that contains your css file. You will have to allow to make changes, once you do this you will see your folder in the sources tree(MAKE SURE YOU SELECT FILESYSTEM TAB UNDER SOURCES TAB), open your folder find the file and right click on the your css file and select map to network resource. Once you map the file you can open and see it in the workspace and from that file any change made will affect the page styles. So basically your styles will over ride the served styles.