# How can I store CSS files loaded from a website and get them applied to another website?

Tags: css, google-chrome

**Detailed Scenario:**

- I opened a tab in google chrome browser
- And in that tab, I browsed a website
- In inspecting element I got the list of CSS files to see for that website
- I want these all files to be stored somehow in google chrome for
  this particular tab
- Next, I  render to another website in the same tab
- Somehow I want the previously stored website's CSS files to be applied to this newly rendered website

**Some folks Who wants reason for such case:**

- I am trying to use on template in JS framework
- the template has custom CSS files
- applied custom template files are minified at browser side when page rendered to the browser from js Framework
- so I am 100% sure some custom CSS files are not getting rendered
   and not even an error is given
- to double check with this doubt and to move in the right direction

  I questioned above case mf.

Answer (score 0):

using bookmarklet

```
javascript: (function () {
    var linkNode = document.createElement('link');
    linkNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
    linkNode.href = 'http://example.com/stylesheets/style.css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(linkNode);
})();
```

create webextension using `content_scripts` API

```
{
 "name": "My extension",
 ...
 "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*/*"],
     "css": ["myStyles.css"],
     "js": ["contentScript.js"]
   }
 ],
 ...
}
```

or ready to use extension stylish https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe

Comment: I will try and get back here

Comment: ewwink while referring to your answer I got correct keywords to search and they are like 
"how to inject CSS 3 using inspect element"
And I got the answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445867/inject-css-with-chrome-developer-tool