# Trying to use css to solve a longstanding Chrome browser issue of briefly displaying page orientation options when printing then hiding it

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, landscape

I am trying to print a webpage (that I have no control over) in landscape orientation using the chrome browser.

As you can see here:

[Chrome Print dialogue not offering fit to page, landscape, other printing options](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3101500?hl=en)

This is a long standing issue.

However, one commenter [suggested using css](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3101500?hl=en&msgid=49033050) to fix the issue.

> Adding following css to your webapp fixes this issue. Google shows Layout options after this fix.
>
> @page { size: landscape; }

I was thinking I could perhaps use developer tools to add that bit of css in, but I am too unfamiliar with css to get it to work.

Can someone explain how/where exactly to add this to the page's style using dev tools to get it to be landscape? I can add css [following these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54613970/11012871), but I suspect I am not adding it in the correct place.

I couldn't find a [style which requested portrait](https://superuser.com/questions/1455052/how-do-i-force-chrome-to-print-a-web-page-in-portrait-mode) to change or remove, but I am sure there are many ways to do that which I am unfamiliar with.

**EDIT:**

Per @Rojo I was able to use the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13883978/11012871) to add the css. Further using [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets), I was able to make the code a snippet, so I can rerun it whenever I need to on any misbehaving page.

Here is the snippet code:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '@page { size: auto; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add css to page via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847313/dynamically-add-css-to-page-via-javascript)

Comment: It is a page I don't own or control, so I can only modify it from the developer tools.

Comment: You can just insert that code in the console as a function

Comment: Hohoho! That did it! I combined made that a snippet, and now I can just run the snippet whenever I want!

Comment: @Rojo, if you want to make that into an answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take this code and insert it into the console.

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = 'content';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

It just creates a new style tag and inserts into the head.